# QML: Unable to get the height of an item, from Loader delegate in a ListView

Tags: listview, qml, components, height, loader

Good morning, all,
I've got a QML component "Help" that is supposed to be a list of heterogeneous types (titles, images, texts, notes). This is implemented as a ListView (based on a QStringList c++ model: Global.helpFields).
Each string of the list contain a prefix (two chars) that indicates the type, and then the rest of the string is the data to format by the proper loader depending on the type of the data.

So far so good. Problems start when I try to get the sum of the "height" of my objects, so I could put the right size for the component and include it in my GUI :

The console.log in the code below always displays: status=undefined , height= 0 , ...

What did I get wrong, if you please?

**Help.qml:**

```
ListView {
    id: _helpList
    ExtraAnchors.horizontalFill: parent;
    spacing: 8
    <...>
    readonly property var helpItems: [
        { prefix: "i:", helper: _imgComponent },
        { prefix: "h:", helper: _headerComponent},
        { prefix: "t:", helper: _txtComponent},
        { prefix: "n:", helper: _notaComponent} ] ;

    model: Global.helpFields // C++ QStringList model

    delegate: Loader {
        id: _helpItem
        focus: (model.index === 0)
        height: (item !== null && typeof(item)!== 'undefined')? item.height: 0;
        property string _sourceValue : Global.helpFields[model.index] ;
        property string _value : _sourceValue.substr(2);
        sourceComponent:  {
            var _prefix = _sourceValue.substr(0,2);
            var length = helpItems.count;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (_prefix === helpItems[i]["prefix"]) {
                    return helpItems[i]["helper"];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            if (model.index === 0) { Global.helpFieldsHeight = 0 ; }

            Global.helpFieldsHeight+=height;
            console.log("status=", Component.status," , height=", height,", _sourceValue=",_sourceValue,", Loader, ", _helpItem.status, ", model.index=",model.index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this line a typo: `Global.helpFieldsHeight+height;`? Should that be `+=`?

Comment: In general, it's not an easy thing to do getting the height of all the elements of a ListView. That's because ListView only creates enough delegates as it needs for the visible display.

Comment: Yes it was a typo @JarMan, thanks for pointing this out. If I put the ListView in a Flickable, maybe I can get it fully displayed, and then scroll it in the window? Or am I on the wrong way and should I reconsider the whole design of my help page?

Comment: I abandoned the design with the ListView and just made a Flickable { ... Column ... Repeater { ... Loader ... [ ... } ... } ... } instead and I'm managing the scroll on the Flickable and it seems to work well enough. Thanks for your insights.